# HTML5 Canvas image upload - uploads blank image or destroyed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, html5-canvas

i am using the code bellow to mix two images and upload it to server as a new single image. For this i am using Canvas.

My html code is:

```
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img1 = loadImage('https://xxxdomain.com/image1.jpg', main);
var img2 = loadImage('https://xxxdomain.com/image2.jpg', main);

var imagesLoaded = 0;
function main() {
    imagesLoaded += 1;

    if(imagesLoaded == 2) {
        // composite now
        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
        ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);

    }


    var myimage = canvas.toDataURL();
    var datasendervars = "myimage="+ myimage;
    alert(myimage);
    $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: "save.php",
    data: datasendervars,
    cache: false,  
    success: function(html){
        alert(html);

       }
});

}

function loadImage(src, onload) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = onload;
    img.src = src;
return img;
}
<script>

<canvas width="700" height="367" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

And my upload php script is:

```
$img = $_POST['myimage'];
  $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
  $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
  $data = base64_decode($img);
  $file = 'tester/img'.date("YmdHis").'.png';

  if (file_put_contents($file, $data)) {
     echo "<p>The canvas was saved as $file.</p>";
  } else {
     echo "<p>The canvas could not be saved.</p>";
  }
```

Image uploads successful but its blank and all uploaded images are the same filesize.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the *ajax post request* incorrectly. It should be ...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save.php",
    data: {"myimage": myimage},
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
    }
});
```

** *also make sure the images are hosted on your local server (same domain)*